# Release methodology for complex distributed system

Tags: automated-testing, test-management, test-design, agile-testing

I have a problem on deciding how to guarantee good testing of a complex distributed system before release. We have an automated testing infrastructure in place. The problem is that running all the tests takes around 5 days (including stress, longhaul etc.).

Let us assume that we start with build V1 of the system and we start testing on that. After 5 days, we look at the results and notice that there are some failures, either due to dev code changes, some due to breakage in the automation. In the meantime, devs continue work on their tasks and after 1 day, we fix all these issues, we get a new build out (V1.1 - which contains more dev changes + changes for the current testing) and we want to start testing again.

Now, the question is, what do we test? Do we spend 5 days running the full bunch of tests on V1.1 or do we run only specific tests for the affected code and pray/hope the components do not break? Can you please suggest some methodology around testing such systems?

One idea that I had was: create a branch in our repository that starting tests "snapshots" the dev branch and starts running the tests on the snapshot. If changes are required to either the dev or automation, those changes are made in the dev branch and cross-integrated to the snapshot branch. This guarantees that only changes for the test pass are in the snapshot branch, but the second problem is still not solved.

Thanks,

/cd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a few extra factors here that can impact the way you handle this problem:

1. Do you get results for each test as it completes or do you have to wait until all tests complete?
2. Do you have multiple machines on which to run the tests (and is it possible to do this) or are you tied to a single system running your tests in sequence?
3. Can you break your tests into smaller groupings?

With a complex distributed system it can be difficult to run tests in parallel, but if you can arrange to do this, it will make managing the automation cycle much less challenging.

Assuming that you *can* set up your tests to run in parallel:

- I'd **start by separating the functional regression tests from the
  stress and load tests**. These are the tests you run daily. If it takes
  more than a day to complete, consider breaking the functional
  regression tests into multiple smaller suites that can be run in
  parallel on numerous machines. You want these scheduled to kick off
  at night so they (ideally) be completed by the time you arrive at
  work in the morning so you can analyze any failures and report
  regressions quickly. This gives you a faster turnaround for purely
  functional tests.
- **For your long-run tests such as the stress tests and load tests**, I'd
  look at generating short versions that can be run in parallel and
  scheduled the same way as the functional tests. These won't give you
  the same level of value as your long-run tests, but they should be
  sufficient to detect any serious problems. Your long-run tests can
  then be scheduled to run say once a week and will pick up any other
  problems. You won't have quite the same level of granularity this way
- but you're always going to be compromising in this situation.

If you *can't* run tests in parallel (you don't have the equipment, the system isn't going to allow it, you don't have the licenses for your automation environment... It's not ideal, but it happens.) I'd suggest you work this way:

- **If your tests aren't already reporting as they complete, set them up to do this**. If you're running them as a single long suite, split it into multiple suites set to run in order. This way you can be analyzing failures before the run completes.
- **Order your tests to put smoke tests and broad functional regression first**. This will give you the earliest possible notification of functional regression issues.

Some things you can do to gather more data faster regardless of whether you can split your automation into parallel runs or not:

- **Each test should report as soon as it completes**. This doesn't have to be a detailed report - a simple X items passed, Y items failed email is enough to alert your team to potential problems.
- **After each test, export all your logs** to a shared network location where you can analyze them while the automation is running the next test. That way, if there's a failure you can start analysis without impacting the current run. (This assumes that each of your tests is a granular sequence that starts with the AUT closed and closes the AUT at the end of the test.)
- **If your tests use a common setup sequence**, consider turning this into a database restore/data flush and reset operation that pulls the data set from a shared network location. I've been in the situation where every test run spent an hour or more configuring data for the actual testing. The team built a once-a-week data configuration automation run and modified the other runs to simply pull the data from the configuration run, reducing setup for the functional runs to about five minutes.
- **Consider going through your tests and replacing static waits with component-dependent waits wherever possible**. It's a lot easier to put a static wait for some number of seconds than it is to code a wait routine that will check for a required component, and return an error if it fails to instantiate and become active within a specified time, but a whole lot slower: if your static wait is 3 seconds and the component exists and is active in 10 milliseconds, the automation will still wait 3 seconds. A fused wait that checks for the component every 100 milliseconds will only wait 100 milliseconds. If your automation has been around for a while, chances are good that there's a lot of static waits scattered through the oldest code (I've never seen an automation code base that didn't evolve and improve over time).

No matter what strategy you choose, you're going to be compromising between completeness and quick turnaround: your goal is really to get the best possible mix of both.

Answer (score 0):

Have a quick smoke test per build, preferably per commit (aka continuous integration). This will ensure (at least to some degree) that your automation and basic product functionality are still working.

Before you start testing a new build meet the relevant stake holders (developers, product managers, marketing) and decide on where to focus your tests based on risk (aka risk based testing), customers requests etc.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Rsf. Its better to divide the automated suite in two parts.

Smoke or quick test part covers (ie samples) all functionality including  in 12 hours duration. if this test-suite has even single failure, consider it is showstopper. Start next testing with this build only once fix is available and verified in Smoke test.

Any failure in remaining testing (of 5 days) should be treated as low priority bug and it should be part of planned bug fix in future release.

Now The question is what should be done  when smoke test is failed and new build is awaited. Should we continue with reaming testing? this is interesting as suppose bug is reported from the subsequent testing
 1. It is possible that bugs reported from this testing could have same cause due to which smoke test has failed. Effectively wasting testing /analysis/development team effort.
 2. It is possible that this bug is unrelated to bug reported in smoke. Effectively the idle period is utilized in finding "real" bug.

```
The Answer is it Depends.
It depends on the dynamics.
```

Although the testing is automated there is always some overhead of running it. 
So one has to consider  historical build stability, development teams capacity of handling bugs. As well as overheads of running automation suite/gains if same bandwidth can be deployed for some other purpose.

Effectively   what to do if smoke test fails depends on situation, and decision may require periodic review.